# uiviewtablecontroller where to retain?

Tags: iphone, memory-management, uitableview

I have a UIViewController and view which has a few objects on it, one being a UITableView. Since I want to separate all the code related to the UITableView into its own class, I have created another subclass of UITableViewController and set the UITableView's delegate and datasource to this new controller.

But setting it up this way I am getting a EXC_BAD_ACCESS because UITableViewController is not being retained. Where should I be retaining it, in the UIViewController? or some place else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to retain a reference in the `UIViewController` since it is where you would have likely created it. Unless retained, the table view controller will get deallocated while the application is running and hence the error.